# Second header sticky on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div id="secondnav">
  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="search-container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically i wanna make my secondary nav as shown become Sticky When the user scrolls past it.

```
.topnav .search-container {
float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
padding: 6px;
margin-top: 8px;
font-size: 17px;
border: none;
border: 1px solid #6E8EE5;
border-right:none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
float: right;
padding: 6px 10px;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-right: 16px;
background: #ddd;
font-size: 17px;
border: 1px solid #6E8EE5;
border-left:none;
cursor: pointer;
 }

.search-container {



}

header {

width:100%;

}

#secondnav {
background-color:#557CAA;
height:50px;
align-items:center;

}

header img {
position: absolute;
margin:10px 50px;
}
#primary nav {
border-bottom: #458DD0 1px solid;
border-top: #458DD0 1px solid;
background-color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 0px;
font-weight:normal;
}

#primary ul {
height:150px;
align-items:center;
width: 600px;
margin:auto;
display:flex;
justify-content: space-around;

}

 #primary li {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;


}

#primary a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 23px;
color:#6E8EE5;

}

 #primary a:hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid #6E8EE5;
}
```

after the user scrolls past the Primary header, i just want it to show the secondary one as a sticky. then when the user goes back up change it back to normal.

Preferably with Javascript.

This is what it looks like https://gyazo.com/51cc30765e15a2cab638ee32e6a7e4bc

So when you scroll past i want the blue part to show and if possible, how could i add a 'Hidden' NAV that will only display when the user scrolls down to it.\

Sorry if this doesnt make sense, ill clarify more if you need it.

Comment: do you use plugin for first one?

Comment: We need more details, such as rest of your **relevant** code (css / javascript)

Comment: updated with a litlte more, no plugin.